# CMIS compatibility: TCK reports data for all ECM products

Tags: data-request, products

[CMIS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_Management_Interoperability_Services) is an interoperability protocol for [ECM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enterprise%20Content%20Management) server products.

**Bad news**: Many ECM server products claims CMIS compatibility, but in fact many do not implement the standard correctly.
**Good news**: There is an easy-to-use open source tool called "TCK" that checks compatibility of an ECM server product and produces an HTML report with metrics.
**Bad news**: Many ECM server products have no trial version, so only people who have bought it (usually extremely expensive) can run the TCK tool on it.

**QUESTION**: Is there a place that gathers the TCK results of each ECM server product?
Hopefully a place where anyone can contribute their own results, under an open license.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found nothing so I created one: http://cmissync.org/CmisCompat

It contains for each ECM server:

- The raw TCK test data
- Some metrics
- A calculated score

[image: CMIS ranking]

Creative Commons CC-BY-SA.
Data is hosted on Github, so collaboration is via pull requests.